# Syncfusion: border for irregular shape?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, syncfusion

Is it possible to do a border on a shape that's composed of smaller shapes (assuming all squares and rectangles) like this? Assuming all shapes are rendered dynamically from system data, and could have new and different shapes as a new shape collection that also needs a border. [image]